# Jenkins and Git configuration issue

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been using Git for sometime now.

Recently, I have started exploring Jenkins and I managed to set it up using the native windows installer. I created a sample project on my local system and built it using Jenkins successfully.

Now, I have a project on remote Server and I want Jenkins to pull this code using Git.

I did the following:

**1) Installed the Git Plugin.**
[image]

**2) In Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Git > Git installations -**

[image]

[also tried C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\gitk.cmd instead of ....\git.exe]

3) Under the Test project > Configure
[image]

4) Finally, tried to build it. But always get timeout error and then failure.
[image]

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\GitTest
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=60
FATAL: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:647)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:889)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:914)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1258)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host git.us1.adeptra.com port 7999: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1435)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1223)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:280)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:645)
    ... 10 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Do i need to provide credentials? (I tried that it failed too)

Comment: are you able to make `git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@<the-url-to-the-server>demo_android.git` on your local computer ?

Comment: Yes. I navigated to the particular directory and executed the command. As usual, it asked for the passphrase and then went ahead and tried to fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it ! The SSH key had a passphrase. I removed it and it worked fine.

Removed the passphrase by following the instructions in the link -

http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/security/ssl/remove-passphrase-password-from-private-rsa-key

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide authentication. Either do that by using plain text and fill it in the config or the command-line, or use a <s>certificate</s> ssh-public-key to do that.

Here you can find **[a tutorial](http://www.cyberswat.com/devops/automate-jenkins-config-management-github)** on how to connect it to GitHub, and I think it should be done likewise on you own **[git-server](http://www.git-tower.com/learn/ebook/command-line/advanced-topics/ssh-public-keys)**.

Comment: I already have id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and known_hosts files on my local system. Where should I provide the authentication in Jenkins?

Comment: You need to verify what user jenkins is running as as test as that user. For me on Linux that would be the Jenkins user itself, as such I have to set the id_rsa key files in the right place for that user, being: home/jenkins/.ssh

Comment: The user who is performing the `git clone`-command, should have its (public) ssh-key submitted to the **git server**

Answer (score 0):

simply go to jenkins -> global tool configuration -> add git -> name(Default) & Path to Git executable (git) -> save